# Why would the fleet hit each other?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Poe says to his team, who are attacking the fleet:

> Poe: Get to their altitude. They can't fire on us **without hitting each
> other**. Don't give up.

Why would the fleet hit each other ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He means that the fire *from their guns* would [hit each other ship that was firing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_fire), given the relatively small size of the Rebel ships and the inaccuracy of the guns on the Star Destroyers.

[image: two configurations of star destroyers. The top one shows them firing below each other. The second one show one firing at the other trying to hit rebel ships]

Their tactic is successful because the Star Destroyers stop using their turbocannons and are forced to rely on TIE Fighters.

Comment: This never made any sense to me. Star Destroyers don't have anti-aircraft guns in addition to their main batteries? They clearly aren't worried about stray TIE fighter fire, so there must be some range of fire power that is still lethal to enemy fighters without being a threat to other Star Destroyers.

Comment: @chepner, there is: they're called TIE Fighters

Comment: Yes, something that has to carry its own fuel and pilot is clearly better than a swarm of guns powered by the ship itself.

Comment: @chepner No one ever said the empire was *good* at what they were doing.

Comment: @Hearth Indeed :) (I think my last comment sounds more snarky than I intended.)

Answer (score 0):

Well disregarding the fact the "ion cannons" look like turbolasers and shred the enemy fighters, the orientation of each destroyer would make hitting those tiny fighters impossible once they begin bombing runs on the superlaser. This is the same reason Lando says: "Yes, I said closer! Move as close as you can and engage those Stardestroyers at point-blank range! .... And we might just take a few of them with us!" (thank you @Mazura). So they had to scramble out fighters.